# Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). DbUpdateConcurrencyException in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

**I am getting the DbUpdateConcurrencyException exception with the title message. Below is the code i am using.**

```
    private TestDBEntities tdbe = new TestDBEntities();
    public int InsertData(CustomerInfo value)
    {
        Customer cst = new Customer();
        int rslt = 0;

        cst.CustomerID = value.CustomerID;
        cst.CustomerName = value.CustomerName;
        cst.Address = value.Address;
        cst.City = value.City;
        cst.PostalCode = value.PostalCode;
        cst.Country = value.Country;

        tdbe.Customers.Add(cst);
        rslt = tdbe.SaveChanges();

        return rslt;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a primary key defined on the `Customer` entity? If there is non in SQL, you can also define it in Visual Studio. Thats only for validation then.

Comment: Can you show us the underlying SQL structure (e.g. CREATE TABLE)?

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic, because this question lack all kinds of context information. Like where does `InsertData` run and what is the life cycle of this class? What are the class definitions (Customer, Country, Address, ...)? What is in the `Entries` of the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`?